# Dynamically display bootstrap accordion using jQuery and JSON when checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am dynamically displaying table values from JSON using jQuery.  What I am trying to accomplish, if when the user selects the false column, a drop down form displays below the row that was selected.  I am using bootstrap accordion to display the new row.

This is what works using this jsfiddle I found on a previous question http://jsfiddle.net/2Dj7Y/1582/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var json = [{"itemNo":"1","itemsToCheck":"Air Recharge Rates","P":"","F":"","defectDescription":"","inspectionCriteria":"Should be less than 4 minutes"},{"itemNo":"2","itemsToCheck":"Governor Cut In","P":"","F":"","defectDescription":"","inspectionCriteria":"Approximately 105 psi"},{"itemNo":"3","itemsToCheck":"Goveror Cut-Out & Air Dryer Purging","P":"","F":"","defectDescription":"","inspectionCriteria":"Dryer purges upon governor cutout pressure @ approx 125 psi"},{"itemNo":"4","itemsToCheck":"Low Air Alarm","P":"","F":"","defectDescription":"","inspectionCriteria":"Audible and visual indication engages at approx. 35-45 psi"},{"itemNo":"5","itemsToCheck":"Parking Brake Safety App","P":"","F":"","defectDescription":"","inspectionCriteria":"Parking brake automatically engages at approx. 35-45 psi"}];
    var tr;
    var hiddentr;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1" class="accordion-toggle">');
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].itemNo + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].itemsToCheck + "</td>");
        tr.append('<td><div class="checkbox form-checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxPass" value="'+json.P+'"></label></div></td>');
        tr.append('<td><div class="checkbox form-checkbox"><label><input data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1" class="accordion-toggle" type="checkbox" value="'+json.F+'"></label></div></td>');
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].defectDescription + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].inspectionCriteria + "</td>");
        tr.append("</tr>");
        $('#airSystemTable').append(tr);
        hiddentr = $('<tr>');
        hiddentr.append('<td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow"><div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo1"> Demo1 </div> </td>');
        hiddentr.append('</tr>');
        $('#airSystemTable').append(hiddentr);
    }
```

});

The problem with this when the user clicks on the row, only the row below the first row displays since they will all map to id="demo1"

So I tried to dynamically change the demo number so it would work for all rows clicked

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var json = [{"itemNo":"1","itemsToCheck":"Air Recharge Rates","P":"","F":"","defectDescription":"","inspectionCriteria":"Should be less than 4 minutes"},{"itemNo":"2","itemsToCheck":"Governor Cut In","P":"","F":"","defectDescription":"","inspectionCriteria":"Approximately 105 psi"},{"itemNo":"3","itemsToCheck":"Goveror Cut-Out & Air Dryer Purging","P":"","F":"","defectDescription":"","inspectionCriteria":"Dryer purges upon governor cutout pressure @ approx 125 psi"},{"itemNo":"4","itemsToCheck":"Low Air Alarm","P":"","F":"","defectDescription":"","inspectionCriteria":"Audible and visual indication engages at approx. 35-45 psi"},{"itemNo":"5","itemsToCheck":"Parking Brake Safety App","P":"","F":"","defectDescription":"","inspectionCriteria":"Parking brake automatically engages at approx. 35-45 psi"}];
    var tr;
    var hiddentr;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo'+(i+1)+'" class="accordion-toggle">');
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].itemNo + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].itemsToCheck + "</td>");
        tr.append('<td><div class="checkbox form-checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxPass" value="'+json.P+'"></label></div></td>');
        tr.append('<td><div class="checkbox form-checkbox"><label><input data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo'+(i+1)+'" class="accordion-toggle" type="checkbox" value="'+json.F+'"></label></div></td>');
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].defectDescription + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + json[i].inspectionCriteria + "</td>");
        tr.append("</tr>");
        $('#airSystemTable').append(tr);
        hiddentr = $('<tr>');
        hiddentr.append('<td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow"><div class="accordian-body collapse" id="#demo'+(i+1)+'"> Demo1 </div> </td>');
        hiddentr.append('</tr>');
        $('#airSystemTable').append(hiddentr);
    }
```

});

Eventually I want it to work when the user checks the fail box but just getting it to work right now like the previous jsfiddle is my priority.

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: probably easier to do this programmatically as in the demo link  instead of trying to increment ID's. Traverses are typically much easier than managing incremental ID

Comment: hi @charlietfl thanks for answering so fast. The reason Im doing it dynamically, especially with the json stored in a vairable, is eventually we will be recieving the json from a url and there could be many more values than what is shown.  This is proof of concept.